# Minimal Pairing

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics, optimization

Your program should take two lists, where each entry (a positive integer) represents the number of members of some group, as input. These lists will have the same sum but may have different lengths.

Your mission, should you choose to accept it, will be to pair up members of the first list with members of the second, outputting a list of triples of the form `(i, j, n)` where `i` is an index into the first input list, `j` is an index into the second input list, and `n` is the number of members of group `i` from the first list who are paired up with a member of group `j` from the second list.

Every member of both lists should be paired up in this way.

In pseudocode, `∀i, sum(n for (i1, _, n) in output if i1 == i) == first_list[i]`, and `∀j, sum(n for (_, j1, n) in output if j1 == j) == second_list[j]`, `all(n > 0 and is_integer(n) for (_, _, n) in output)`, where `first_list` and `second_list` are the two input lists, and `i` and `j` range over valid indices into the respective inputs.

Your output list must have minimal length among all valid solutions. Zero-based and one-based indexing are both acceptable. Shortest answer wins.

#### Example

Input: `[3, 4, 5] [5, 6, 1]`

Possible optimal output: `[(0, 1, 3), (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 1), (2, 0, 5)]`

```
   list 1    list 2     i  j  n
  [ 3 0 0 ] [ 0 3 0 ]  (0, 1, 3)
+ [ 0 3 0 ] [ 0 3 0 ]  (1, 1, 3)
+ [ 0 1 0 ] [ 0 0 1 ]  (1, 2, 1)
+ [ 0 0 5 ] [ 5 0 0 ]  (2, 0, 5)
---------------------
= [ 3 4 5 ] [ 5 6 1 ]
```

#### Test cases

The test cases use zero-based indexing.

```
[3, 4, 5] [5, 6, 1]  ->  [(0, 1, 3), (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 1), (2, 0, 5)] (length 4 optimal)
[4, 3, 1, 5] [2, 1, 3, 7]  ->  [(1, 2, 3), (2, 1, 1), (0, 3, 4), (3, 3, 3), (3, 0, 2)] (length 5 optimal)
[1, 7, 5] [4, 5, 4]  ->  [(0, 0, 1), (1, 2, 4), (1, 0, 3), (2, 1, 5)] (length 4 optimal)
[4, 5, 5] [3, 7, 4]  ->  [(0, 2, 4), (1, 1, 5), (2, 0, 3), (2, 1, 2)] (length 4 optimal)
[4, 3] [3, 1, 3]  ->  [(0, 0, 3), (0, 1, 1), (1, 2, 3)] (length 3 optimal)
[4, 3, 2] [4, 5]  ->  [(0, 0, 4), (1, 1, 3), (2, 1, 2)] (length 3 optimal)
[] [] -> [] (length 0 optimal)
```

Comment: Challenges must have an [objective scoring criterion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8130/why-do-we-have-objective-winning-criteria). I would recommend [tag:code-golf]. In future, please post your questions in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) first to get feedback

Comment: @pxeger Oops, forget to mention that code-golf was intended.

Comment: @user1502040 Are [these chat messages](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56674137#56674137) an adequate description of your challenge?

Comment: I've read this probably 50 times and I'm no closer to understanding the problem than the first time I read it.

Comment: @ZaelinGoodman Sorry for the poor wording. It should be more understandable now.

Comment: Here's my attempt to translate the idea of the challenge into a more accessible form: You have some of cats of different breeds and the same total number of dogs of different breeds. You want to split them all into groups, each of consists of cats all of one breed and an equal number of dogs all of one breed. How can you do this with as few groups as possible?

Comment: @xnor Exactly right.

Comment: @xnor thank you; I don't know if I'm particularly dense or this is still a difficult challenge to understand, but your explanation finally clicked (after reading it and applying it to the test cases in the question a couple more times). I'd recommend adding xnor's explanation to the challenge, to help other people who just aren't getting it like I wasn't - might help it to get re-opened. I like the challenge (now that I get it) and, though I can't cast reopen votes yet, I've upvoted the challenge in hopes of gaining the attention of those who can :)

Comment: Also using the terminolgy "pair up" is confusing when we are supposed to output triples.  It leads me to think incorrectly that each triple somehow represents a pair.  I suggest using terminology that more closely matches xnor's example.  Rather than pairing them up, talk about putting them into groups, since each tuple represents a group.

Comment: I've added a detailed example. Feel free to rollback or edit further.

Comment: @Arnauld I think that detailed example is a great improvement. I did understand the challenge, but at the same time it wasn't particularly clear, so I hadn't open-voted it yet. With this added example it does make it a lot clearer what is being asked, without needing to understand the Python-style pseudo-code and deducting what the challenge asks exactly based on the test cases alone, so now I have open-voted.

Comment: @Arnauld Thanks, that was a great idea. Slightly wish i'd had it!

Comment: @ZaelinGoodman Thanks, glad to know my confusing phrasing didn't turn you off for good!

Answer (score 4):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>222..187</s> 180 bytes

*-7 bytes thanks to [user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792)!*

```
x=>y=>{var(a,b,r)=(x,y,Set[Any]())
while(a.sum>0){var?,m=a.max min b.max
var p,q= -1
while(p<0|q<0){if(p<0)p=a indexOf?
if(q<0)q=b indexOf?
? +=1}
a(p)-=m
b(q)-=m
r+=Seq(p,q,m)}
r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDLbsIwEEX3/ooRK1sYRKAUCeEgllVbdYG6Ql04YIqrxDiJoUlpvj11HkBAhZXnce7M9cRL7vN8632JpYFnEIkRahXDTGs4IIA99yGQSgbc749hFkU8XTwp8wHMvcrmwixmKrVxnjA3Ze5hzyPMqUcjwnBCU3okMCHoeyN9gXk33gVujxTolAaMdwOeFPvAKyJky6BpyKDj1Ao96f2GE6uQ6yImmnGQaiWSt/UU2VrRC5l3rk2hzZwMcaxJhwXIw2H5Rm02FyG2w2lAMhRlOcBKrI9/xUnzsxTSZkqAnW6CE4JTgupL6Ugq81q1xoCbEy7kLrwraYBZGYC9DaRl8VDm1ajtzuidOW@qqBoo9/gKV9B1tfUi1KfZjKEF7XpON5Y/4pqr8qww3zRe2cYDCg8UhqS2jocUHik4hPyPW9YqnKaiX@a2Orolsu1RU1EstGvv7Bg28UEpv4cPmmxh5r79/oWTW@wJsgDK8j8)

Comment: You can use `:+=`, but it would be even easier to make it a `Set[Any]` to use `+=`[180 bytes](https://tio.run/##fZDLbsIwEEX3/ooRK1sYRKAUCeEgllVbdYG6Ql04YIqrxDiJoUlpvj11HkBAhZXnce7M9cRL7vN8632JpYFnEIkRahXDTGs4IIA99yGQSgbc749hFkU8XTwp8wHMvcrmwixmKrVxnjA3Ze5hzyPMqUcjwnBCU3okMCHoeyN9gXk33gVujxTolAaMdwOeFPvAKyJky6BpyKDj1Ao96f2GE6uQ6yImmnGQaiWSt/UU2VrRC5l3rk2hzZwMcaxJhwXIw2H5Rm02FyG2w2lAMhRlOcBKrI9/xUnzsxTSZkqAnW6CE4JTgupL6Ugq81q1xoCbEy7kLrwraYBZGYC9DaRl8VDm1ajtzuidOW@qqBoo9/gKV9B1tfUi1KfZjKEF7XpON5Y/4pqr8qww3zRe2cYDCg8UhqS2jocUHik4hPyPW9YqnKaiX@a2Orolsu1RU1EstGvv7Bg28UEpv4cPmmxh5r79/oWTW@wJsgDK8j8)

Comment: @user thank you for your tips :)

Comment: You can save [3 more bytes](https://tio.run/##fZA9b8IwEIZ3/4oTky0cRKAUCeEgxqqtOlSdUAcHTEmVGCcxNCnNb0/tJIWACpPv43nvXl@65CEvt/6nWGp4BJFpIVcpzJWCAwLY8xCiQAYRDwcTmCcJzxcPUr8D8y6yV6EXc5mbuMyYlzPvsOcJ5tSnCWE4ozn9IzAh6GsThALzXrqLvD6x6IxGjPcintl94NsImTIoGjNw3Eahpv2feGoUwdrGRDEOgVyJ7GU9Q6ZmezHzT7UZdJlbII4VcViEfBxXb9JlyvFix4sKlBQlwEqs/z6Ks/ZPKeTtlAA7HgRnBOcENWdSSSD1c92aAG5POJN78CYDDczIAMxhIK@KhyqvR213Wu30aVNNNUC1J5S4hi6rnSchP/RmAh3oNnN6afAtLrk6L6z5tvHaNh5SuKMwIo11PKJwT8El5H/csEbhthWDKjfV8TWRaY/bCrvQrL2xY9TGh5X8Fj5ss9bMbfuDMyfX2CNkAFSUvw), but the encoding of the triples would become a bit uglier :(

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 137 bytes

```javascript
a=>g=(b,k=O=0,o=[],n,c)=>O=O&&!O[k]||a.map((p,i)=>b.map((q,j)=>b[a[i]-=n=p<q?p:q,b[j]-=n,n&&g(b,k+1,[...o,[i,j,c=n]]),a[i]=p,j]=q))|c?O:o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc/BbsMgDADQ@76CXSLQXNo0zSpVc/sJ@QDEgbA0C82ArNVO@fcM0lRTqx7CyTZ@Nhj1q876p/GXhXWf1XDEQeG@RlrCCQtcgUMhwYJmuC@wSJLXQpxk3yv@rTylHppwUV6TDkxMhBKNXKBF/9Ed/K6DUpiYg02SOs59S0Fwzh2IBgxotFIyiAg9GIkdY70@FDs3aGfPrq1462p6pCIDsgGSS0ZFDuQdSCoZI9ezXJK2svXli2xeHlgwQaaTXI9hKGwj/mf5Iwtd28nErWH33G35xLJxwmyWTSYdw5u5Y9nzv61vj5zLYv9dL3nGVsMf)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>                           // outer function taking the 1st list a[]
g = (                          // inner function taking:
  b,                           //   the 2nd list b[]
  k = O = 0,                   //   k = length of current solution, O = output
  o = [],                      //   o[] = current solution
  n,                           //   n is a local variable
  c                            //   c is a flag telling whether both lists are cleared
) =>                           //
  O =                          // update O:
    O &&                       //   abort if an output is already defined
    !O[k] ||                   //   and it's shorter than the current solution
    a.map((p, i) =>            //   otherwise, for each value p at position i in a[]:
      b.map((q, j) =>          //     for each value q at position j in b[]:
        b[                     //
          a[i] -=              //       subtract n from a[i]
            n = p < q ? p : q, //       where n = min(p, q)
          b[j] -= n,           //       subtract n from b[j]
          n && g(              //       if n > 0, do a recursive call:
            b,                 //         pass b[] unchanged
            k + 1,             //         increment k
            [ ...o,            //         update the solution o[]
              [i, j, c = n] ]  //         with the triplet [i, j, n]
                               //         and set the flag c
          ),                   //       end of recursive call
          a[i] = p,            //       restore a[i]
          j                    //
        ] = q                  //       restore b[j]
      )                        //     end of inner map()
    ) | c ?                    //   end of outer map(); if c is set:
      O                        //     leave O unchanged
    :                          //   else:
      o                        //     update O to o
```